# WordPress - Each page of paged posts all show same posts

Tags: wordpress

I set up a pagination function for my wordpress blog. When clicking to the next page, the URL is correct: "/page/1", "/page/2", "/page/3" etc, but the actual posts don't change from page to page (page 2 and page 3 still display the first page of posts). Here's the code I'm using for the loop:

Edit 4/24/10: I removed the 'offset' => 1, parameter and the paging now works, but now the question becomes: how do I use the offset parameter and still page?

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$sticky=get_option('sticky_posts');
$args=array(
 'offset' => 1,
 'category__not_in' => array(-6),
 'paged'=>$paged,
 'showposts' => 6,
   );
query_posts($args);
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Any help/insight would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How to:  Offsets and Paging «  Weblog Tools Collection](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2008/06/19/how-to-offsets-and-paging/) and [WordPress › Support » Query_posts, offset and pagination](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/320679?replies=12)

Answer (score 2):

I removed the `'offset' => 1,` parameter and the paging now works, but now the question becomes: how do I use the offset parameter and still page?

Comment: LOL I had ` 'offset' => 0,` and the pagination was broken because of that.